# Obtener elementos hermanos de un boton javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Me gustaría saber como puedo obtener los valores de los elementos img y span cuando le doy click al botón agregar. Estos divs se generan de una llamada a una base de datos y requiero obtener los valores de los demas elementos dentro del div donde se encuentra el boton al que le di click. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
<div class='divplato'>
   <img src='.../foto1' alt='' id='foto1'>
   <span class='namemostrar'id='nombre1'>Nombre</span>
   <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' id='idbtn1'>Agregar</button>
</div>"

<div class='divplato'>
   <img src='.../foto2' alt='' id='foto2'>
   <span class='namemostrar'id='nombre2'>Nombre</span>
   <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' id='idbtn2'>Agregar</button>
</div>"

<div class='divplato'>
   <img src='.../foto3' alt='' id='foto3'>
   <span class='namemostrar'id='nombre3'>Nombre</span>
   <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' id='idbtn3'>Agregar</button>
</div>"
```

Comment: Mírate las funciones closest() (para subir al elemento padre), y querySelector() (para luego buscar el elemento img y el span para sacarles los valores a partir del padre encontrado).  Inténtalo y si no lo consigues actualiza la pregunta con lo que hayas intentando, pues ahora mismo la pregunta no sería válida porque no has intentando nada, solo dices lo que quieres que te hagamos.

Comment: Si, error mío, no mandé lo que había probado, pero muchas gracias con lo que me comentaste logré hacerlo.